# How to add translatable string in function parameter?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wpml

I have a javascript function in a wordpress script, I need it to be compatible with WPML chain translation

```
ubp_show_error("<p>Inutile de l'ajouter plusieurs fois</p>");
```

How can I make this chain to be something like this :

```
ubp_show_error(_e('<p>Inutile de l'ajouter plusieurs fois</p>','mytheme'));
```

I've tryed :

```
$error = _('<p>Inutile de l'ajouter plusieurs fois</p>','mytheme');
ubp_show_error($error);
```

but in javascript, this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [localize](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) your script.

**PHP**

```
function custom_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('your-script', '/your-script.js');
    wp_localize_script('your-script', 'your_js_obj_name', array(
            'error' => __("<p>Inutile de l'ajouter plusieurs fois</p>",'mytheme')
        )
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_load_scripts');
```

Now you have access to that data in your javascript file like:

**JS**

```
your_js_obj_name.error // --> '<p>Inutile de l'ajouter plusieurs fois</p>'
```

Comment: ok thank you, so I need to replace the loading of this script, or I can add this to my functions.php ? And so I replace the error message in JS file with your ?